# Using embedded MongoDb in Spring Boot application along with MongoTemplate fails

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have Spring Boot application:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication()
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

}
```

build.gradle contains:

> testCompile group: "de.flapdoodle.embed", name:
>   "de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo", version: "2.0.0"

and

> compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")

There's controller which uses MongoTemplate

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(Constants.MAILBOX_BASE_PATH)
public class MController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MailboxController.class);

    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public MController(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }
}
```

And test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MontrollerTests { 

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    private MongoTemplate _mongoTemplate;
...
}
```

My intention is to use embedded MongoDB for the above test.
When i run it the following error is popped:

> 2017-03-05 17:14:51.993 ERROR 27857 --- [           main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'mController' defined...

and at the of the stacktrace there's

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid mongo configuration, either
>   uri or host/port/credentials must be specified

My application properties:

```
server.port=8090
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/test
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

How to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need mongo template reference in test. The test will create a embedded mongo template and autowire into controller when you have flap doodle dependency on classpath. Thats pretty much what you need. If that doesn't work trying adding `@EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration` annotation explicity in your test class.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try creating a `@Bean` for `mongoTemplate` with `EmbeddedMongoFactoryBean` class? e.g.:

```
@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws IOException {
    EmbeddedMongoFactoryBean mongo = new EmbeddedMongoFactoryBean();
    mongo.setBindIp("127.0.0.1");
    MongoClient mongoClient = mongo.getObject();
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, "some_database");
    return mongoTemplate;
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks. where do you propose to put the bean function? In application class?

Comment: Yes, that class or any class annotated with `@Configuration`

Comment: the same error pops and for EmbeddedMongoFactoryBean i had to download some library

Comment: Absense of library should have resulted in `ClassNotFoundException`, not sure why that was not the case

Comment: i have added the library, then ran the test again and the same error popped

Comment: Could you please check whether this bean gets created? If yes, could you try adding `@Primary` annotation on this method?